# How do I get a Lexmark X2600 printer working?

Tags: printing, lexmark

I can't get my Lexmark X2600 printer working. I tried a lot of things find over the net but without any success.

Is there a really big brain who can help me? I really love 12.04 release (64 bits) and I NEED my printer working.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the driver, do this:

```
sudo modprobe usblp
sudo chown -Rh root:root /usr/local/lexmark
sudo chown -Rh root:root /usr/lib/cups
/etc/init.d/cups restart

gedit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd
```

**Find**:

```
# FIXME: no policy ATM for hplip and Brother drivers
/usr/bin/hpijs Ux,
/usr/Brother/** Ux,
```

**Copy and Past after this**:

```
/usr/local/lexmark/lxk08/bin/printdriver Ux,
/usr/lib/cups/backend/lxkusb Ux,
/usr/local/lexmark/lxk08/bin/lxkusb Ux,
```

**Save the file**

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings either on your status bar or search for it. 
Then you should find the hardware options (click it) then plug your printer into your computer. 
It should automatically ask you if you want to download drivers for the printer. 
Download the drivers then click on the printer tab (you should still be in the hardware settings) the computer should now check for the appropriate drivers and install your printer. 
Print the Test Page (should work) :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by installing the ia32-libs package:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Then it's a matter of checking to see whether it works on plugin, or if you have to try installing the driver from Lexmark. After looking at it, seems to me the Lexmark installer mentioned by newbies2005 should work after installing the 32-bit compatibilities package from above. If the installer doesn't automatically install the driver you need, maybe you can manually add the .PPD driver from the /usr/lexinkjet/lxk08 directory as shown in the readme that displays when you run the installer. I would be willing to connect to your computer with teamviewer.com and help directly if you can't get it working. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

humm srry for my bad english :(

i see that you use ubuntu 12.04 with 64 bits in my casse i make the installation of the driver on my laptop with ubuntu 11.04 64 bits.

try to follow the instructions step by step;

1/ download the driver: http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=DR860&docLocale=en_US&segType=driverSegmentLINUX_UNIX

2/create a folder and unzip "lexmark-inkjet-08-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.zip" in it

3/execute  lexmark-inkjet-08-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh in root

4/normally you will receive this error message; Please Install CUPS Version 1.2 or Higher and Run the Installer Again

5/This error happens when Ubuntu, Debian and other operating systems that are DPKG package base also has an RPM package manager installed.

6/remove RPM package, use the command: sudo apt-get remove rpm and retry step 3

7/you will receive another error message that tell you the installation is failed

8/this error message is due to the uncompatibility of the 32 bits lexmark driver within your ubuntu 12.04 64 bits

9/so to success the installation you need to force the installation of the driver.

10/go to this site and follow the instructions: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=lexmark_linux&num=4

Comment: si tu utilise ubuntu en français je pense que ca seras mieux que j'ecris en français,

Est-que l’installateur de lexmark apparaît sur ton écran quand tu l'as excuté avec le shell dans le terminal?